# Automator: How to send an email to multiple recipients with Font colour and attachment image?

Tags: email, applescript, automator, font, attachments

I have done a program of 'Send-Email-To-Multiple-Recipients' in Automator as see an attachment image below.

[image: Image1]

But, it does not work to retain font colour of texts in a message body within this program.
Also, wondering how to attach an image between the lines.
It might be to use AppleScript rather than Automator.

Please give me a piece of advice or useful example if you are kind.

Cheers,

M

Comment: Is the text/image of the message static?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there is no direct way. You would have to use applescript to select the text and set the formatting in the Mail application after the fact... (Example below taken from the web...)

```
tell application "System Events" to tell (process 1 where frontmost is true)
    set {c1, c2} to value of attribute "AXSelectedTextRange" of text area 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1
end tell
tell application (path to frontmost application as text) to tell document 1
    tell characters c1 thru c2
        set font to "Menlo"
        set size to 18
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply. So sad the fact there is no directly way. Hope someone else kindly help me out.

Comment: That answer was good enough for me thus the + point :)